# Xcode Embed WatchOs Content - change app name for one scheme based

Tags: xcode, watchos

On my build phase i have the following step :

[image]

My app have many scheme (flavors) how to change the name here which seems not be editable ? I would one based on my current scheme.

For example :
ClientA.app in build/Debug-clienta-watchos
ClientB.app in build/Debug-clientb-watchos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed watch content want to aim a target name. Target name should be fix and not scheme dependent. A target name like 'app', 'watch' can have variant. My error was to try working with flavored target names. :)